# docker claims running container but there are no running containers

Tags: docker

I am trying to delete images, but it claims they being used by running containers.

There is nothing running.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

```
$ docker rmi $(docker images -q)
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 605a0f683b7b (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 226c646dbf89
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 1399a72fa1a9 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 663e14c4aebc
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete e534b1952a0d (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 28c9cdec51ce
```

However, if I try to stop that last container it responds.

```
$ docker container stop 28c9cdec51ce
28c9cdec51ce

$docker container rm 28c9cdec51ce
28c9cdec51ce
```

But then if I try to delete again... I get the same number of "running container" errors. Just with different IDs.

```
$ docker rmi $(docker images -q)
$ docker rm $(docker images -a -q) # or this
$ docker rm $(docker images -qa) # or this


Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 605a0f683b7b (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 226c646dbf89
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete cbd7f21fec99 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 222a6e775d16
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 1399a72fa1a9 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 663e14c4aebc
```

It feels like the containers are *self healing* somewhere automatically. docker ps still returns nothing.

How do I delete these ghostly containers? I have ran system prune.

---

**EDIT**:
See how it is switching the 'running container ID'

```
$ docker rmi 605a0f683b7b
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 605a0f683b7b (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container bc1e6ac79fd5

$ docker container stop bc1e6ac79fd5
bc1e6ac79fd5

$ docker rmi 605a0f683b7b
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 605a0f683b7b (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container d60860fdea86
```

Comment: first check with `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` then try `docker rmi $(docker images -aq)`

Comment: Please file a bug report! Claiming a container was running when it isn't is a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: Weird... after restarting docker a bunch of times `docker rmi $(docker images -aq)` worked.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4577

Comment: docker ps shows active containers, 'docker ps -a' would show you all containers, including dead containers that are technically still 'running' according to docker daemon. So is it possible you had some hanging containers still being used, hence why you couldn't delete the images?

Answer (score 0):

Delete or remove your container first afterward you can remove an image.

```
docker ps -a
sudo docker rm container_id -fv
```

now try to remove the image.

```
sudo docker images
sudo docker image rm image_id -f
```